# How to turn off tooltips in wxpython

Tags: wxpython

I have tried:

```
wx.ToolTip.Enable(False)    
wx.ToolTip_Enable(False)
```

and

```
wx.ToolTip.Enable(flag=False)
```

none of theses instructions are rejected and yet none of them work
I'm using `Linux Mint 17` `wx.python 2.8.12.1 (gtk2-unicode)` `python 2.7`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer in the end for individual tooltips was gloriously simple and yet took an age to find.
Set the tooltip with `SetToolTipString("my Tool Tip")` but remove it with `SetToolTip(None)` see below:
The global turning on and off of tooltips still seems to be controlled by your desktop environment.

```
import wx
class MyForm(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Toggle")
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.dummy = wx.StaticText(self.panel, -1, "")
        self.cb1 = wx.CheckBox(self.panel, -1,"Choice 1", pos=(10,10))
        self.cb2 = wx.CheckBox(self.panel, -1,"Choice 2", pos=(10,40))
        self.cb1.Bind(wx.EVT_CHECKBOX, self.onToggle1)
        self.cb2.Bind(wx.EVT_CHECKBOX, self.onToggle2)
        self.cb1.SetToolTipString(wx.EmptyString)
        self.cb2.SetToolTipString(wx.EmptyString)
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onToggle1(self, event):
        if self.cb1.GetValue() == True:
            self.cb1.SetToolTipString("Check Box 1 is Checked")
        else:
            self.cb1.SetToolTip(None)

    def onToggle2(self, event):
        if self.cb2.GetValue() == True:
            self.cb2.SetToolTipString("Check Box 2 Is Checked")
        else:
            self.cb2.SetToolTip(None)

# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the wxpython [docs](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/ToolTip.html#ToolTip.Enable), `ToolTip.Enable` seems to,

> Enable or disable tooltips globally.
>
> Note May not be supported on all platforms (eg. Cocoa).

Which I assume includes your platform...
Instead, you may need to set the tooltips for the window itself. There isn't a `ToolTop_Enable` method I can see for the window but setting the tooltip to an empty string seems to do the trick for me,

```
import wx

app = wx.App()

frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, '')
frame.SetToolTip(wx.ToolTip(''))
frame.SetSize(wx.Size(300,250))
frame.Show()

app.MainLoop()
```

EDIT: Define a child tooltip class which can be enabled/disabled and defaults based on a global value.

```
import wx

EnableTooltips = False

class Tooltip(wx.ToolTip):

    '''A subclass of wx.ToolTip which can be disabled'''

    def __init__(self, string, Enable=EnableTooltips):
        self.tooltip_string = string
        self.TooltipsEnabled = Enable
        wx.ToolTip.__init__(self, string)
        self.Enable(Enable)

    def Enable(self, x):

        if x is True:
            self.SetTip(self.tooltip_string)
            self.TooltipsEnabled = True
        elif x is False:
            self.SetTip("")
            self.TooltipsEnabled = False         

app = wx.App()

frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, '')
tt = Tooltip('test')
frame.SetToolTip(tt)
frame.SetSize(wx.Size(300,250))

frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

I'm not sure this will work dynamically (i.e. once you start the gui, the frame tooltips have been set and changing their value may not update).

Comment: Thanks for replying Ed but if you have defined a tooltip and simply want to be able it turn it off. Your solution sadly does not work. I guess that I just have to accept the fact that in my current environment, I will not be able to turn them off.

Comment: My efforts at lateral thinking by setting wx.ToolTip.SetDelay(25000) didn't work either, probably for the same reason as the original issue. So as a last resort one can edit the $HOME/.gtkrc-2.0 file and add gtk-enable-tooltips= 0 which will turn off tooltips globally or use the slightly less draconian gtk-tooltip-timeout=5000 which will globally set tooltips to only show if you have hovered for 5 seconds. Sadly, the manual says that as of Gtk 3.1 both of these have been deprecated and no alternative appears to be offered. Why can't we choose to toggle tooltips on and off?

Comment: Does seem a bit of an oversight. In the spirit of lateral thinking, what about defining a child class that can be enabled and use a global flag in your code? I've edited above a possible solution.

Comment: Hi Ed, thanks for that. If fact that is along the lines of what I ended up doing. I used a global defining On, Partial and Off and use that to decide which tooltips will be defined on Start up. For your information, I regularly change tooltips on the fly, which works a treat. Regards Rolf.

Comment: Hi Rolf, Glad you got it working. If your solution is significantly different, it would be good to put it as a separate answer so it can help people in the future with a similar question (or edit above and accept if trivial).

Comment: Hi Ed, sorry to disappoint but it is much simpler than that. I read a config file which has a setting for the tooltips and depending on the value, I do or do not create the tooptips. It isn't clever but it works a treat. If some reason a tooltip needs to be shown later, I define it on the fly.